# Efficiently viewing log files

Tags: neovim, folding

I have a log file, with each line containing log level `{NOT_SET/TRACE,DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}`.
I would like to have the following functionality:

- Define custom levels and their priority
- Hide all messages below certain priority threshold
- Adjust priority threshold dynamically, while being able to do all normal operations on remaining text. e.g if I scroll down with some lines hidden, and then reduce threshold, I should stay on the same line with new lines appearing above and below.
- Optionally also support multi-line messages: i.e. given a line with known level, all further lines should have the same level, until a line with new level is found.

I'm using neovim 0.7.0

How can I accomplish this?
Perhaps there is already a working plugin with such functionality?
I did a brief search in vim awesome, but couldn't fine anything like that.
The closest I found is https://github.com/embear/vim-foldsearch, but it doesn't have the threshold functionality.

P.S.

- `:g/` is not enough for me.
- I don't subscribe to `VIM IS NOT AN IDE` idea.

Comment: I'll let the question stand as-is because I don't immediately have time to make the necessary edits, but generally "plugin requests" are off-topic. Instead, consider an [edit] to rephrase the question around the specific problem you want to solve, to which "try this plugin" may be an answer. (This also enables you to receive other kinds of answers!)

Comment: Perhaps you can still use vim-foldsearch and use a search regex that would cover all log levels above the threshold? You could build some mappings or a plug-in on top of that to do handle this specific functionality around your log files.

Comment: Write all your logic in a function and `set foldexpr=YourFunc` and `set foldmethod=expr`